WKWebview not painting the screen unless touched
We have an ios app (using MAUI) that hosts a Web view (WKWebview on iOS).
Content rendered in Web view is a simple react app.
I have noticed sometimes the webview gets into a state that it won't paint what is supposed to be on screen unless you touch the screen.
Say you press a button and the react app adds a new text to screen or changes the color of the button. I can see that JS has finished running and Dom is updated but the screen is not showing the what DOM has until you touch the screen.
Is this a known problem?
More Observations

if you inspect the DOM you can see that it tries to highlight elements on the screen. So you see the pale blue highlighter around where the elements should be but they are not rendered and you see previous screen there.
if you subscribe to next paint cycle (requestAnimationFrame) your callback gets called as soon as you touch the screen.

